# Nominalization for being "not convex" and "not coercive"

Tags: terminology, convex-analysis

Having a function `f` which is neither convex nor coercive. What is the correct nominalization for these properties? I suppose something like

```
non-convexity and non-coercivity of f
```

Additionally, is it correct to say

```
f is non-coercive
f is non-convex
```

Maybe this is a question for MathOverflow...

Comment: "Exponential growth is a special case of **convexity** ." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)  "... in the sense of **coercivity** of a vector field, ..." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function)

Comment: Btw, could you please vote to move this question? Or should I simply ask it there again?

Comment: I suppose the question is answered now. Would you like the citations to be posted as a formal answer?

Comment: It's not a vector field and therefore not "coercitvity", but "to be coercive". This means for `|x|` going to infinity `f(x)` also has to.

Comment: No Kris, it is not answered.

Comment: I've suggested migration, let's see.

Comment: @Kris Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm not a native speaker of English</sup>

> non-convexity and non-coercivity of $f$

Yes, these are frequently used: "The non-convexity of $W(\nabla u)$ implies...",  "in spite of the non-coercivity of $A$...", "due to non-coercivity of the Hamiltonian..."  Google Scholar search brings up these and many others.

The combination of both may be appropriate in the introductory part: "additional challenges are presented by the non-convexity and non-coercivity of $f$". I would not use it in the course of a proof, because it packs too much mathematics into one sentence. The sentence "... fails due to the non-convexity and non-coercivity of $f$" is likely to be improved by separating it in a way that shows the role of those two factors.

> $f$ is non-coercive; $f$ is non-convex

You can say that, but I see no advantages compared to "$f$ is not coercive", "$f$ is not convex", "$f$ is neither coercive nor convex". These  versions sound simpler and avoid  any dispute about "non-convex" vs "nonconvex" (the journal you submit to may have a different preference from yours). It also handles line breaks better.